# select row that column2 not equal to column1

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I need help with a SQL Query

I have this table

```
likes
 friend    friend2
      1          2
      2          1
      3          1
      4          5
```

I need to select only one pair of the friends that like each other.

With my current select I'm obtaining this

```
 id     name         id     name
1709    Cassandra    1689   Gabriel 
1689    Gabriel      1709   Cassandra
1501    Jessica      1934   Kyle    
1934    Kyle         1501   Jessica
```

but the expected query result is:

```
 id     name        id     name
1709    Cassandra   1689    Gabriel 
1501    Jessica     1934    Kyle
```

Comment: Which database and version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that every pair is entered in the database twice (once as A, B and again as B,A) then you can use this:

```
 SELECT friend, friend2
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE friend < friend2
```

If there can be some pairs that are only entered once, then you can use this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
     LEAST(friend, friend2) AS friend,
     GREATEST(friend, friend2) AS friend2
 FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select *
from
(
    select
        case
            when id1 > id2 then id2
            when id1 < id2 then id1
        end as Friend1,
        case
            when id1 < id2 then id2
            when id1 > id2 then id1
        end as Friend2
    from TestMatching
) a
group by Friend1, Friend2
```

What this does here is it uses a subquery and the subquery is just a couple of `CASE` blocks to order the friendship.  And then it does a group by to create the summary of friendships.  If you wanted to see what friends are BOTH ways, then you'd do something like this:

```
select *
from
(
    select
        case
            when id1 > id2 then id2
            when id1 < id2 then id1
        end as Friend1,
        case
            when id1 < id2 then id2
            when id1 > id2 then id1
        end as Friend2
    from TestMatching
) a
group by Friend1, Friend2
having COUNT(*) > 1    -- this is the added clause to get consenting friends
```

The result query is all the friends that are friends with each other.